# Is it ok to use the local repository in maven?

Tags: java, maven

So I recently switched to using my local repo in maven to save time with dependency management, like this:

```
<repository>
   <id>local</id>
   <url>file://C:/Users/REDACTED/.m2/repository/</url>
<repository>
```

Now this code works, but is this deprecated in any way?

Comment: You Clan also use -o option ( offline mode) instead of using a local repository.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: `save time with dependency management, ` ? In which way? What are the problems?

Comment: No, its just that I find adding all the repositories tiring.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say where you put that XML: in the project's POM file or in your local `settings.xml` file.

I would say that it would not be a good idea to put a local repository into a POM file, because it ties your project to a file location that is incorrect for ... other people who might need to build your project at some point in the future.  (For example, someone whose user name is not "REDACTED".)

Other drawbacks of hardwiring your (only) repository to be a local one are:

- You have to add all of your project's dependencies to your local repo by hand.
- You won't automatically pick up any updates to those dependencies from their source repo.  This mostly applies to SNAPSHOT dependencies.

Obviously, >>you<< need to decide if any of those points are relevant to your project and work practices.

---

> ... is this deprecated in any way?

The Maven team would be the only people with the standing to label this as "deprecated", and I don't think they have.

---

I think you are using the word "deprecate" inappropriately here.

In the general English sense, "deprecate" means "to express disapproval of (something)".  This is a pretty broad meaning ... and not a common usage.

In the IT context, deprecation generally refers to a software product or feature of some kind; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software).  It *typically* means that that the "something" is being withdrawn or removed in some way ... and/or you are recommended to stop using it.  The recommendation *typically* comes from the software vendor themselves.

You seem to be using it the context of a "practice".  I don't think the Maven team use it that way.  If they were to say something about this, they would *probably* call it a recommendation.

My opinion is that some people in the IT world use "deprecated" in the same way that (other) people use "best practice".  That is, they use it to convey a **false** sense of authority to what they are saying.  (Please read [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164) to get a sense of what I mean by this.)

In short:

- If you mean "deprecated" in the general English sense, that part of your question is close to meaningless.
- If you mean "deprecated" in the "good" IT sense (i.e. an official statement from the Maven team), then No, it isn't.
- If you mean "deprecated" in the "bad" IT sense, you are (literally) asking for a statement made with (probably) false authority.

  Not a good idea.  Ask what you actually mean.  For example, ask *"Can someone give reasons why I should / should not do this?"* and then *make up your own mind* whether the reasons apply to your context.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you.